# Last_Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT 
    year(h.orderdate)*100+month(h.orderdate) as yearmonth,
    YEAR(h.orderdate) as orderyear,
    sum(d.OrderQty*d.UnitPrice) as amount

  FROM [AdventureWorks].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] d
        inner join sales.SalesOrderHeader h
        on d.SalesOrderID=h.SalesOrderID
 group by
    year(h.orderdate)*100+month(h.orderdate),
    year(h.orderdate)
)

select
    c.*,
    last_value(c.amount) over (partition by c.orderyear order by c.yearmonth) as lastvalue,
    first_value(c.amount) over (partition by c.orderyear order by c.yearmonth) as firstvalue
from cte c
order by c.yearmonth
```

I am expecting to see the lastvalue of each year (say december value), similar to the firstvalue of each year (jan value). however, last_value is not working at all. It just returns the same value of that month. What did I do wrong?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the default row range for [`LAST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, so the value you are getting is the current month's value (that being the last value in that range). To get `LAST_VALUE` to look at *all* values in the partition you need to expand the range to include the rows after the current row as well. So you need to change your query to:

```
last_value(c.amount) over (partition by c.orderyear order by c.yearmonth
                           rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as lastvalue,
```

Comment: Hi Nick, I followed it up by reading a bit more about these windows functions. Here is an article I found it very helpful and hope it can help with someone else https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/ . Again thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ronald that looks pretty comprehensive. The manual page (see the link I posted in the answer) is actually quite well written too and has some good examples in it.